# Pyaudio - test computer speakers?

Tags: python-3.6, pyaudio

I am trying to put together some code in Python 3.6 to help test the computer hardware that passes through my hands as an IT tech.

I'd like to have a script that plays a simple sine wave tone on the left speaker, then the right and then the both speakers together.

I have found a potentially helpful script over at [Pyaudio How to get sound on only one speaker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30071822/pyaudio-how-to-get-sound-on-only-one-speaker) but some of the code to actually run it is missing - chiefly the code for making sin wave tones. I have looked around online and have tried reverse-engineering this back into the code on that page but the maths is a little high-level for me! Sorry.

Thanks,

Will

Update:
I think I have found a partial (albeit long-winded solution) with 'sounddevice' for python 3

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import argparse
import logging

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=__doc__)
parser.add_argument("filename", help="audio file to be played back")
parser.add_argument("-d", "--device", type=int, help="device ID")
args = parser.parse_args()


try:
    import sounddevice as sd
    import soundfile as sf
    data, fs = sf.read(args.filename, dtype='float32')
    sd.play(data, fs, device=args.device, blocking=True, mapping=[1])
    status = sd.get_status()
    if status:
        logging.warning(str(status))
except BaseException as e:
    # This avoids printing the traceback, especially if Ctrl-C is used.
    raise SystemExit(str(e))
```

The main chunk of code is repeat twice more but with "mapping = [1]" changed to "mapping = [2]" to test the right speaker and finally with "mapping = [?]" removed in the final block to test both speakers.

I found this over at https://python-sounddevice.readthedocs.io/en/0.2.1/examples.html.

Of course, if anyone knows a quicker and graceful way of getting this done, please share!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could generate the sine tone directly in Python instead of loading it from a file. I've written some tutorials about creating simple sine tones:

- https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/mgeier/python-audio/blob/master/simple-signals.ipynb
- http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/spatialaudio/communication-acoustics-exercises/blob/master/intro.ipynb

Those tutorials use NumPy, because it makes manipulating the audio buffers very easy. But you can of course also do it in pure Python, if you prefer.
Here's an example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import math
import sounddevice as sd

sd.default.device = None
sd.default.samplerate = samplerate = 48000

duration = 1.5
volume = 0.3
frequency = 440

# fade time in seconds:
fade_in = 0.01
fade_out = 0.3

buffer = memoryview(bytearray(int(duration * samplerate) * 4)).cast('f')

for i in range(len(buffer)):
    buffer[i] = volume * math.cos(2 * math.pi * frequency * i / samplerate)

fade_in_samples = int(fade_in * samplerate)
for i in range(fade_in_samples):
    buffer[i] *= i / fade_in_samples

fade_out_samples = int(fade_out * samplerate)
for i in range(fade_out_samples):
    buffer[-(i + 1)] *= i / fade_out_samples

for mapping in ([1], [2], [1, 2]):
    sd.play(buffer, blocking=True, mapping=mapping)
    sd.sleep(500)
```

Note that this code is using 32-bit floating point numbers (each one using 4 bytes), that's why we reserve 4 times more bytes in our `bytearray` than the required number of samples.

Comment: Excellent. That seems to work. I will spend a bit of time tweaking the script and brushing up on my math!